# incrementing a buffer array address not changing the start address of array as shown in printf

Tags: c

so I have an array that I want to skip few characters so I can print when after the first few characters in array this is my code

```
  char in_buffer[8000]={0};
  memcpy(in_buffer,REQUEST_1,8000);
  *(in_buffer+3);
  printf("%s\n",in_buffer);
```

in this line I am skipping 3 characters in the start (adrress +3) then do
`printf("%s\n",in_buffer);`

but I am getting printf from the start of buffer

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
```

in above output characters in start `GET` should not print. how can I do this like skipping few charaters with incrementing array address with indirection operator

**Update**

I have this function

```
void print(char *array)
{
  printf("%s\n",array);
  if(strncmp(array,"\r\n\r\n",4)!=0)
  print(array+1);
  else{return;}
}
```

array contains

```
#define REQUEST_1 "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" \
"Host: localhost:5000\r\n" \
"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:93.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/93.0\r\n" \
"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" \
"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n" \
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n" \
"Connection: keep-alive\r\n" \
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n" \
"Sec-Fetch-Dest: document\r\n" \
"Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate\r\n" \
"Sec-Fetch-Site: none\r\n" \
"Sec-Fetch-User: ?1\r\n\r\n\0" \
```

it does the same thing to increment the address but it gives segFault so actually what I am doing is I recursively call print function with advancing address and check if `\r\n\r\n` found then if found just return. But its not working what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `in_buffer += 3;`

Comment: @user3386109 I am getting `req.c:43:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
   43 |   in_buffer += 3;
      |             ^~` error with `in_buffer+=3`

Comment: Oops, `char *bufptr = in_buffer + 3;` and then `printf("%s\n", bufptr);`

Comment: @user3386109  why its not working in my function call can u please look at the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
*(in_buffer+3);  // Expression result unused
printf("%s\n",in_buffer);
```

should be:

```
printf("%s\n",in_buffer + 3);
```

Comment: can u please see the update to question

Comment: thanks I was making mistake in updated question code. thanks for help

Comment: @user786 If you have a different, unrelated question, then ask a new question instead of using edit to this one.